# Solution architecture - Asset download and App size on iOS ecosystem

Tags: ios, streaming, unity-game-engine

I am currently architecting a solution for the iOS and am well versed with the Unity game engine. However, I have a couple of questions pertaining to Apple and hosting applications on the AppStore.

1) I am planning on my application having a thin client and downloading assets and code (in Unity terms - Asset Bundles) as and when the application needs it. Do these assets and code have to be verified through Apple? Can my app download directly from my server without any Apple or AppStore intervention?

2) Assuming the answer for the above questions are in affirmative, does Apple have a limit on the amount of size that an app can occupy on a device?

3) How much of the above applies to the Android EcoSystem?

These questions are necessary to be answered for my solution architecture.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you are not allowed to download code that will be executed by your mobile application.